# Python Spotify Refresh Token

Tags: python, spotify

I am trying to get a refresh token but I keep getting a 400 error.  Below is my code.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
clientid="xxx"
refreshkey="xxx"
secretkey="xxx"
spotifyurl="https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
spotifydata = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token':refreshkey}
response = requests.post(spotifyurl, data=spotifydata, auth=(clientid, secretkey))
```

Comment: This part of your code looks fine to me. Have you ensured the variables you use look correct at the time where you make the call? Have you tried doing this using cURL to see if you can get a refresh working in general for the client id/secret and refresh token you have?

Comment: When I run the following curl command I get “invalid_client”

curl -H "Authorization: Basic client_id:secret_key" -d "grant_type=refresh_token" -d "refresh_token=refresh_token" "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

Answer (score 1):

My head it sore from banging it against the wall but I finally figured it out.  I was using the node.js example provided by Spotify to get my initial token and refresh token.  Turns out their html page has an error that adds an extra ">" at the end of the refresh key.